# SMARTY 3: Throw exception(not Notice) if variable undefined

Tags: smarty, smarty3

Is there a way to force Smarty 3 throw exceptions instead of notices?
I want application to crash in there is undefined variable.
In smarty 2 there was error_unassigned param, but looks like it's removed in v3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$smarty->error_unassigned = true;` still exists. A method to throw Exceptions on unassigned variables does not exist (yet), though. You could [set_error_handler()](http://php.net/set_error_handler) to convert the notice to an exception.